# How to make the txPanel visible only after the 'enter pin ok' button has been clicked?

Tags: java, swing, applet, jbutton, actionlistener

```
public class ATMgui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 500;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 200;
    private ATMbizlogic theBLU;// short for the Business Logic Unit
    public JLabel totalBalanceLabel;
    public JTextField withdrawTextField;
    public JTextField depositTextField;
    public JTextField pinTextField;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of ATMgui
     */
    public ATMgui() {
        setTitle("ATM Transactions");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        // Do the panel for the rest stop
        JLabel start = new JLabel("Welcome To Your Account", JLabel.CENTER);
        Font curFont = start.getFont();
        start.setFont(new Font(curFont.getFontName(), curFont.getStyle(), 25));
        start.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        start.setOpaque(true);
        start.setBackground(Color.BLACK);


        pinTextField = new JTextField();
        JLabel pinLabel = new JLabel("Enter your PIN below:", JLabel.CENTER);
        pinLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        pinLabel.setOpaque(true);
        pinLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



        JButton pinButton = new JButton("Enter Pin OK");
        pinButton.addActionListener(this);
        pinButton.setBackground(Color.red);

        JPanel pinPanel = new JPanel();
        pinPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 100, 0));

        pinPanel.add(pinLabel);
        pinPanel.add(pinTextField);
        pinPanel.add(pinButton);

        contentPane.add(pinPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);


        JPanel headingPanel = new JPanel();
        headingPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        headingPanel.add(start);

        contentPane.add(headingPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        // Do the panel for the amount & type of transactions
        withdrawTextField = new JTextField();
        JLabel withdrawLabel = new JLabel("Withdraw (0.00)", JLabel.CENTER);
        withdrawLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        withdrawLabel.setOpaque(true);
        withdrawLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



        depositTextField = new JTextField();
        JLabel depositLabel = new JLabel("Deposit (0.00)", JLabel.CENTER);
        depositLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        depositLabel.setOpaque(true);
        depositLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



        JButton txButton = new JButton("Transactions OK");
        txButton.addActionListener(this);
        txButton.setBackground(Color.red);




        JPanel txPanel = new JPanel();
        txPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1, 30, 0));

        txPanel.add(withdrawLabel);
        txPanel.add(withdrawTextField);
        txPanel.add(depositLabel);
        txPanel.add(depositTextField);
        txPanel.add(txButton);

        contentPane.add(txPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        txPanel.setVisible(true);


        totalBalanceLabel = new JLabel("Your balance after transactions: ", JLabel.CENTER);
        totalBalanceLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        totalBalanceLabel.setOpaque(true);
        totalBalanceLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);


        contentPane.add(totalBalanceLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        theBLU = new ATMbizlogic();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

        // Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        if (actionCommand.equals("Transactions OK")) {
            try {
                double deposit = Double.parseDouble(depositTextField.getText().trim());
                double withdraw = Double.parseDouble(withdrawTextField.getText().trim());
                theBLU.computeBalance(withdraw, deposit);
                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Your balance after transactions: " + theBLU.getBalance());

            } catch (ATMexception ex) {
                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Error in deposit or withdraw amount: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        } else if (actionCommand.equals("Enter Pin OK")) {

            try {

                double pin = Double.parseDouble(pinTextField.getText().trim());
                theBLU.checkPin(pin);

                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Your balance after transactions: " + theBLU.getBalance());



            } catch (ATMexception ex) {
                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Error in pin: " + ex.getMessage());

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error in button interface.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ATMgui gui = new ATMgui();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a code is a good thing but maybe you should add some explanation about your problem and target the part of the code that seems to be the problem.

Comment: okay, so I made an instance variable public JPanel txPanel; and after creating the panel I placed txPanel.setVisible(false); But I don't know where in the actionCommand.equals("Enter Pin OK") part I have to place txPanel.setVisible(true);

Comment: @Jason : Do check my latest edit, and let me know is this working as expected ?

Comment: @GagandeepBali - OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH! TOTALLY WORKED! :)

Comment: @Jason : Hehe, Your Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Comment: @Jason : Do check that I had modified your `checkPin(...)` method, it is returning a `boolean` value instead of `void` and moreover, I had commented the second condition in that method. Have a look is this working as expected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code pasted by you is not working, I had made a small program for you, have a look, and see what changes can you do to incorporate that in your case :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PanelTest extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel eastPanel;

    public PanelTest()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        Container container = getContentPane();

        eastPanel = new JPanel();
        eastPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
        westPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        container.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        container.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        eastPanel.setVisible(false);

        JButton showButton = new JButton("Click Me to Display EAST JPanel");
        showButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                eastPanel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        JButton hideButton = new JButton("Click Me to Hide EAST JPanel");
        hideButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                eastPanel.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        container.add(hideButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        container.add(showButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new PanelTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And from future, never use `NORTH`, `EAST`, `WEST` and `SOUTH` for `BorderLayout`. They have been replaced with `PAGE_START`, `LINE_START`, `LINE_END` and `PAGE_END` respectively.

**A BorderLayout object has five areas. These areas are specified by the BorderLayout constants:**

- PAGE_START
- PAGE_END
- LINE_START
- LINE_END
- CENTER

***Version note: 
Before JDK release 1.4, the preferred names for the various areas were different, ranging from points of the compass (for example, BorderLayout.NORTH for the top area) to wordier versions of the constants we use in our examples. The constants our examples use are preferred because they are standard and enable programs to adjust to languages that have different orientations.***

**I had modified the `checkPin(...)` method of the `ATMLogin` class to return a `boolean` instead of void, so that inside the `actionPerformed(...)` method of the `ATMgui` class, if this thing returns true, then only to set the required `JPanel` to visible, else nothing is to be done.**

Do check the code and see what changes you can do to make it work for your end.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ATMgui extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 500;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 200;
    private ATMbizlogic theBLU;// short for the Business Logic Unit
    private JPanel txPanel;
    public JLabel totalBalanceLabel;
    public JTextField withdrawTextField;
    public JTextField depositTextField;
    public JTextField pinTextField;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of ATMgui
     */
    public ATMgui() 
    {
        setTitle("ATM Transactions");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        // Do the panel for the rest stop
        JLabel start = new JLabel("Welcome To Your Account", JLabel.CENTER);
        Font curFont = start.getFont();
        start.setFont(new Font(curFont.getFontName(), curFont.getStyle(), 25));
        start.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        start.setOpaque(true);
        start.setBackground(Color.BLACK);


        pinTextField = new JTextField();
        JLabel pinLabel = new JLabel("Enter your PIN below:", JLabel.CENTER);
        pinLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        pinLabel.setOpaque(true);
        pinLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



        JButton pinButton = new JButton("Enter Pin OK");
        pinButton.addActionListener(this);
        pinButton.setBackground(Color.red);

        JPanel pinPanel = new JPanel();
        pinPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 100, 0));

        pinPanel.add(pinLabel);
        pinPanel.add(pinTextField);
        pinPanel.add(pinButton);

        contentPane.add(pinPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);


        JPanel headingPanel = new JPanel();
        headingPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        headingPanel.add(start);

        contentPane.add(headingPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        // Do the panel for the amount & type of transactions
        withdrawTextField = new JTextField();
        JLabel withdrawLabel = new JLabel("Withdraw (0.00)", JLabel.CENTER);
        withdrawLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        withdrawLabel.setOpaque(true);
        withdrawLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



        depositTextField = new JTextField();
        JLabel depositLabel = new JLabel("Deposit (0.00)", JLabel.CENTER);
        depositLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        depositLabel.setOpaque(true);
        depositLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



        JButton txButton = new JButton("Transactions OK");
        txButton.addActionListener(this);
        txButton.setBackground(Color.red);




        txPanel = new JPanel();
        txPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1, 30, 0));

        txPanel.add(withdrawLabel);
        txPanel.add(withdrawTextField);
        txPanel.add(depositLabel);
        txPanel.add(depositTextField);
        txPanel.add(txButton);

        contentPane.add(txPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        txPanel.setVisible(false);


        totalBalanceLabel = new JLabel("Your balance after transactions: ", JLabel.CENTER);
        totalBalanceLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        totalBalanceLabel.setOpaque(true);
        totalBalanceLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);


        contentPane.add(totalBalanceLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        theBLU = new ATMbizlogic();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

        // Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        if (actionCommand.equals("Transactions OK")) 
        {
            try 
            {
                double deposit = Double.parseDouble(depositTextField.getText().trim());
                double withdraw = Double.parseDouble(withdrawTextField.getText().trim());
                theBLU.computeBalance(withdraw, deposit);
                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Your balance after transactions: " + theBLU.getBalance());

            } 
            /*catch (ATMexception ex) 
            {
                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }*/ 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Error in deposit or withdraw amount: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        } 
        else if (actionCommand.equals("Enter Pin OK")) 
        {

            try 
            {               
                double pin = Double.parseDouble(pinTextField.getText().trim());
                if(theBLU.checkPin(pin))
                    txPanel.setVisible(true);
                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Your balance after transactions: " + theBLU.getBalance());               
            } 
            /*catch (ATMexception ex) 
            {
                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }*/ 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                totalBalanceLabel.setText("Error in pin: " + ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Error in button interface.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ATMgui gui = new ATMgui();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ATMbizlogic 
{

    private double totalBalance;
    private boolean rightPinEntered;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of ATMbizlogic
     */
    public ATMbizlogic() 
    {
        totalBalance = 0.0;
        rightPinEntered =  true;
    }

    public void computeBalance(double withdraw, double deposit)
    //throws ATMexception 
    {
        if(withdraw <=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Negative withdraw not allowed");
            //throw new ATMexception("Negative withdraw not allowed");
        }   

        if(deposit <=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Negative deposit not allowed");
            //throw new ATMexception("Negative deposit not allowed");
        }   

         double balance = deposit - withdraw;

        totalBalance = totalBalance + balance;
    }

    public boolean checkPin(double pin)
    //throws ATMexception 
    {
        if(pin <=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Negative pin not allowed");
            rightPinEntered = false;
            //throw new ATMexception("Negative pin not allowed");
        }   
        /*else if(rightPinEntered == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Can not take another pin");
            rightPinEntered = false;
            //throw new ATMexception("Can not take another pin");
        }*/ 
        else if(pin<1111 || pin>9999)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid pin");
            rightPinEntered = false;
            //throw new ATMexception("Enter a valid pin");
        }
        else
        {       
            rightPinEntered = true;
        }

        return rightPinEntered;
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return totalBalance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice work, but I can't see how yours can be the right answer to the question asked by the user. We don't know if the user knows what BorderLayout is, and, also, you didn't explained why the user should use a BorderLayout. Please note, mine it isn't a criticism against you, I want only to know the reasons of your answer. :-)

Comment: @AlbertoSolano : Nah, I just read this line in the code and many other lines which goes like this `contentPane.add(headingPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);` and `contentPane.add(pinPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);`, there is nothing so special about `BorderLayout`  for this case. I just used what he was using :-) No doubt, I liked your answer too , but seems like i forgot to upvote that , just after upvoting the first answer I started with my work. :( My bad

Comment: I understood, sorry, I didn't noticed well the BorderLayout lines in the code.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano : No worries, just Keep Smiling :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the right way to implement ActionListeners for buttons.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {   
       String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

      // Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        if (actionCommand.equals("Transactions OK"))
        else ...
    }
```

With the if-else stamements in the method actionPerformed, your program is forced to check what listener to invoke, every time whatever button is pressed, and, in this way, your code isn't easy to edit and reuse.
Also, the GUI Container is acting like a receiver of events, then you should avoid

```
pinButton.addActionListener(this);
```

Try to implement your own inner classes for each button, like this:

```
JButton pinButton = new JButton("Enter Pin OK");
        pinButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                    //enter here your action
                                     txPanel.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
```

In this way, you don't need to implement the ActionListener interface for your class, because you're implementing a inner istance of the interface for your `pinButton`. Check [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779589/is-there-a-better-practice-for-listeners#1780062) of SO.
Also, you should avoid to implement all your GUI elements in your class constructor, it's better to implement the GUI in a separate method, like `createAndShowGui()`, and call it in the constructor, to respect the [Java Swing conventions](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html) and to run the Swing components in a different thread, called [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), different from the main thread of your application. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182316/java-swing-libraries-thread-safety).

Then include `txPanel.setVisible(false);` in `createAndShowGui()` method.

Remember that the Swing components are not thread-safe.

Comment: I liked this Java Swing Convention doc referred by you it helped me get some insight related to `invokeLater` and `invokeAndWait` thingies :-)

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali I'm glad that document helped you, it's very useful! ;-)

Comment: Hey, this is class that the actionPerformed(ActionEvent e ) refers to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691524/how-to-mdify-the-computebalance-method-making-sure-that-amounts-are-positive-a

Comment: @Jason I read the question and I'm glad you solved that. Now the actionPerformed problem is needed to solve :-)

Comment: okay, so I made an instance variable
public JPanel txPanel;

and after creating the panel I placed
txPanel.setVisible(false);

But I don't know where in the actionCommand.equals("Enter Pin OK") part I have to place txPanel.setVisible(true);

Comment: @Jason Ok, place it in the try block. If it doesn't work, follow my suggestions.

Comment: Remove the 'implements ActionListener' from the class name declaration, remove the class method actionPerformed, and implement each single listener for any button, like I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

In the call to constructor ATMgui(), put

```
txPanel.setVisible(false);
```

and in the actionCommand.equals("Enter Pin OK") part, you can set it to true.

Is that what you want?

Comment: +1, seems to me the right solution, seems like the OP is doing some mistake, or he forgot to make `txPanel` an Instance Variable in his case :-)